# Can't get XAMPP, PHP & MySQL up and running

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I've tried using Microsoft WebMatrix and XAMPP but, not matter what I do or what workaround I try, I cant get PHP and MySQL working.

When I install XAMPP, there is a conflict with port 80 so Apache wont start. Then I change the port that it listens to to 9260 and it starts. But after I do this `http://localhost:9260/phpmyadmin/` gives me the following errors and wont allow me access

> *#*1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO),
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection.You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I've been trying to fix it for days and I'm driven around the bend. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: read the install instructions for mysql. Or google for that very error to receive 652,000 hits.

Comment: The last time I had troubles with that port it was skype messing around. Try to close it. Also try WAMP, I find it better than XAMP.

Comment: xampp is running, you dont know the database user and password ... thats all

Comment: and mai you have no password, have you tried using root as user and '' as password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 80 Issue:
Most likely you are running Skype or some other software which already uses port 80. Solution:

1. Open Actions - Options
2. Expand Advanced
3. Click Connection
4. Uncheck "Use Port 80 and 443 as ...."

Refused connection:
In the majority of cases localhost as host is correct. If you are sure, that there is no default password set for root user, your host is not correct - try:

- 127.0.0.1
- mySQL-Server Network IP
- mySQL-Server Name (server.mydomain.eg)

Answer (score 0):

Man if you're using skype just start the XAMPP then skype.

REMEMBER ONE SERVICE PER PORT. Skype switches to another port automatically.